# How to output multiple objects with different names using for loop in R

Tags: r

I'm attempting to write an R script in a way that remains as automated as possible. To this end, I am trying to create a for loop to execute a function on multiple files. The outputs need to be saved as objects for the purposes of the program I am using and therefore each output from the for loop needs to have a distinct name. This is the code I have so far:

```
filenames <- as.list(Sys.glob("*.ab1"))

SeqOb <- list()

for (i in filenames) 
{
  SeqOb <- readsangerseq(i)
}
```

"readsangerseq" is the function I'm attempting to execute to create multiple SeqOb objects. What I've read from other discussions led me to create an empty list in which to store my output objects, but I can't seem to figure out how to make the for loop write them as distinct outputs.

Comment: Rather than using a for loop, just use `lapply`. That will collect all the results into a list for you. `SeqOb  <- lapply(filenames, readsangerseq)`

Comment: Thanks so much! I felt like I was skirting around the answer this whole time. Still have a ways to go in learning R so thanks for helping me along the way!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to continue using the for loop and want distinct outputs instead of a list you may consider using assign(paste()) in order to give each file a unique object name. Although, as a relative newcomer to R myself, I'm starting to learn there are more elegant ways than for loops as well, such as MrFlick's answer.

```
for (i in 1:length(filenames)) {
#You may be able to substitute your function in the line below
assign(paste("SomeNamingRule", i, sep = ""), (readsangerseq(i)))
}
```